# TypeScript omit parameter of function or make it optional based on generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

**How to omit or at least make optional the last parameter of function based on generics?**

```
interface Requests {
     post: {
         data: {
             test: number
         }
     }
     patch: {
         data: {
            test?: number
         }
     }
     get: never
 }

const makeRequest = <Method extends keyof Requests>
   (method: Method, data: Requests[Method] extends {data: infer Data} ? Data : never)
 => { /* ... */ }

makeRequest('post', { test: 1 })  // that's ok, second parameter is required
```

Here I should be able to not pass anything as second parameter since `data` in `patch` has nothing required

```
 makeRequest('patch', {})   
 makeRequest('patch')  // this gives an error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
```

Here the second parameter should be omitted, since it does not have data. If not possible to omit it completely, at least the empty object should not be required

```
makeRequest('get') // error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
```

Comment: Probably better ways to represent it but here's the first thing I came up with: https://tsplay.dev/mMl7zN

Comment: @kelsny Agree, one possible way is [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Comment: @Behemoth I don't see how function overloading will resolve this, How can I define 2 separate function types based on generics.

Comment: @kelsny that seems interesting, is it possible to make it work without affecting the JS, without rest operator and array destructuring

Comment: Not really. This is the only way to describe a parameter that is conditionally required. You would need function overloading for that.

Comment: The effect on JS is minimal anyhow. The behaviour does not change in any way whatsoever. Only the definition of the arguments have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using function overloads, you would have to conditionally make the second parameter required. The only way to do this would be to destructure a conditionally typed tuple.

A more experienced TypeScript conjurer may find a way to reduce this to only 1 conditional, but alas, here's what I came up with:

```
const makeRequest = <Method extends keyof Requests>
   (...[method, data]:
    Requests[Method] extends { data: infer Data }
      ? Partial<Data> extends Data ? [method: Method, data?: Data] : [method: Method, data: Data]
      : [method: Method]) => { /* ... */ }
```

We still have your original check that tests if it even has a `data` property. However, I will note that for this check to work properly, you can't have `never` in `Requests` (`never` is an empty union so it breaks the distributive conditional type).

I would just keep it simple and use `undefined` or `void` in `Requests`:

```
interface Requests {
     post: {
         data: {
             test: number
         }
     }
     patch: {
         data: {
            test?: number
         }
     }
     get: undefined // changed never to undefined
}
```

And finally, the special condition I added, `Partial<Data> extends Data`, is just a way to see if everything in `Data` is optional (because only then would `Partial<T>` be assignable to `T`).

It is worth to note that this kind of typing would likely cause type errors when trying to create the implementation for `makeRequest`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQI4FcIGcy7IDeAUMucgA4D2+AXMWRcwCZxhwOnM8WT3IQWALYAjaAG4mvAL5Tmc6VXYIAFlyWt2nRr178wAfgZCxkzRUUL5FAOYQwDLCBYQYoCCykySJBNRB8ZGE4AGsIdGw8MGQAXmQAHgBZB1VqFmQIAA9IF0JwgE9qGDRMHHxcAD4ACiUAOgaAbWFU9IAaZDYOAF0GSPKCRpSwNJZuzJyIPOJO7QZQGGhkABFtZB89ZENkAAU4KDBgOAAbBNWOSonclkJzuAtebebWlgZh0Y6uuGMV7W6HngMZ4jdJvF6fOa-HoAoEtEGvZDvdL-ACUcUu3AoAHoAFTIBp1ZA4rEkRQkELhfrRaoAIho+BpHSIyAMDAAjOsUVIKREytS6SpVIziDIueSwryovhaZRBTSxTyqdKafYwPKpEA)

---

Here's what overloads *could* look like. You could definitely have 3 signatures, but my implementation got too complicated for what I would like...

```
type KeysThatAreObjects<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

function makeRequest<
    K extends Exclude<keyof Requests, KeysThatAreObjects<Requests>>,
>(method: K): void;
function makeRequest<K extends KeysThatAreObjects<Requests>>(
    ...args: Partial<Requests[K]["data"]> extends Requests[K]["data"]
        ? [method: K, data?: Requests[K]["data"]]
        : [method: K, data: Requests[K]["data"]]
): void;
function makeRequest(method: keyof Requests, data?: unknown) {
    // implementation
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQI4FcIGcy7IDeAUMucgA4D2+AXMWRcwCZxhwOnM8WT3IQWALYAjaAG4mvAL5Tmc6VXYIAFlyWt2nRr178wAfgZCxkzRUUL5FAOYQwDLCBYQYoCCykySJMAE9KFABpCH9cABVVdgBBKAgAeVEAKwgEAgAeCIA+ZABeXQoAbWDkUGQAazDqGGQIgF0GCJL65AgAD0gXQmoUtLBkQ2RSkwgAN3MZIqr-Grr6qRIYZ3TgahBkYTgq9Gw8MAylUo6ulkIAUXaEABssVwyZud2cfFwAGmGwyOiwOMS+9K4DLPfa4bLZN4kbIACmEDlU1BYDGCAEoGGNqMAvEsVmA1hstjtMC8DsdOhBup9wlFYvEkqlAcDiaDwdClAA6TlwKC2XAMAAK3LxcGuTL2rxaRQARGwOFL6rkThSzmhmRLgvVpbK4PKLOQhkU4WAEUjhh9tcZVeKCJKZdp5fU9cgGIb4YjkebtAwQerNXa5fVHWjkBisVJliBVutNtsID6wLC3abHrV4+9kBanCAKiBqAB3EAowrkAD0JbKwko1wgcPA7HxJB8JEJcbVCalNHwUo+RGQBgYAEZkDIUVIW-HoR2VKpu8QR2PYxOp2A1FLR83F23J-YwGupEA)